# Clojure cancellable timer

Tags: timer, concurrency, clojure, channel

I experienced a problem which I have no experience to solve.

I need something like timer with state in Clojure that can receive messages and accumulate them.

I am waiting for 5 seconds.

When I receive for example: [:left id] message to this timer, it should be cancelled and some action with this id executed. When I receive [:entered id] message to this timer I should accumulate it (if less than 5 id's received). When I receive 5 :entered messages with different ids, I should do one action and cancel the timer, otherwise when there is not enough id's entered, do other action after 5 seconds.

My friend adviced me to use channels, but we didn't manage to implement this with channels.

The main problem with that is that timer should have its internal state which should be kept somewhere, but when you use "go", you can't do this, just execute some function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Java `Timer` along with a atom to accumulate state.  Here is an example of what you can do:

```
(def timer (Timer.))
(def state (atom [] ))
(def timer-delay 5000) ; millis

(def timertask
  (proxy [TimerTask] []
    (run []
      (println "timer done")
      (println "state = " @state)
      )))

(defn start-timer []
  (println "starting timer")
  (.schedule timer timertask timer-delay))

(defn add-to-state [item]
  (Thread/sleep 500)
  (println "  adding:" item)
  (swap! state conj item))

(start-timer)
(Thread/sleep 2000)
(add-to-state :first)
(add-to-state :second)
(add-to-state :third)
```

with output:

```
starting timer
  adding: :first
  adding: :second
  adding: :third

timer done
state =  [:first :second :third]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interesting in clojure-only solution. With Java I know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is one of the `ScheduledExecutorService`s from the `java.util.concurrent` package. They are easy to set up and can be stopped and reset without too much trouble. Interop with Clojure is also very easy. (In my opinion, it's easier than using them in Java.)

Here's an example using a `SingleThreadScheduledExecutor` set up to generate a recurring call every five seconds.

```clj
(ns cncltimer.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (java.util.concurrent Executors ScheduledExecutorService
                                 ScheduledFuture TimeUnit)
           (jline Terminal)))

(def executor (Executors/newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor))
(def fyutchur (atom nil))
(def state (atom []))

(defn run-every-five-seconds
  "Hightlight the contents of the specified tab."
  []
  (reify Runnable
    (run [this]
      (println "Five seconds have passed."))))

(defn cancel-future-if-needed
  "Cancel a future, if it exists. Does not interrupt
   the task if it has already started."
  []
  (when (and (not (nil? @fyutchur))
             (not (.isDone @fyutchur)))
    (.cancel @fyutchur false)))

(defn re-schedule-executor
  "Cancel any existing futures if needed and reset to
  a new delay period."
  []
  (cancel-future-if-needed)
  (reset! fyutchur (.scheduleAtFixedRate executor (run-every-five-seconds)
                                         5 5 TimeUnit/SECONDS)))

(defn shutdown-executor
  "Cancel any futures from running and shutdown
   the exector that schedules things to run."
  []
  (cancel-future-if-needed)
  (.shutdownNow executor))

; If running with lein, use "lein trampoline run"
(defn -main [& args]
  (re-schedule-executor)
  (let [t (Terminal/getTerminal)]
    (loop [k (.readCharacter t System/in)]
      (if (= k 75)
        (shutdown-executor)
        (do
          (when (= k 13)
            (swap! state conj k)
            (println "@state:" @state))
          (if (and (= k 13)
                   (>= (count @state) 5))
            (do
              (println "one action")
              (shutdown-executor))
            (recur (.readCharacter t System/in))))))))
```

You can run this with leiningen using the command line `lein trampoline run` and enter some data from the keyboard. If you do nothing, it will just keep printing "Five seconds have passed.". Press the `Enter` at any time to accumulate data into the state variable. Press `left arrow` to shut down the timer and exit. Anything else should be ignored. Something runs every five seconds until the program accumulates 5 "enter" events or is stopped with the left arrow key.

The `jline` stuff (I used version 0.9.94) is just for keyboard handling in the demo. It probably isn't needed for your real program. Likewise, the use of `trampoline` is just so the keyboard will be handled correctly. It may not be needed for your program.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interesting in clojure-only solution. With Java I know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

here is one more blueprint:

```
(defn make-timer [sec exit-fn enter5-fn]
  (let [data (atom [])
        five-entered? (fn [] (->> @data
                                  (filter #(= (first %)))
                                  (map second)
                                  distinct
                                  count
                                  (<= 5)))]
    (future
      (loop []
        (println :tick @data)
        (if-let [[_ exit-id] (some #(= (first %) :exit) @data)]
          (future (exit-fn exit-id))
          (if (five-entered?)
            (future (enter5-fn))
            (do (Thread/sleep (* 1000 sec))
                (recur))))))
    #(swap! data conj %)))
```

It creates the loop with delay in a separate thread, and returns the funtion you can use to update timers inner state. When the goal is reached, the loop breaks.

you can use it like this:

```
(def send! (make-timer 5
                       (partial println :exit)
                       (partial println :entered-5)))

(send! [:exit 100])
;; after 5 seconds prints ":exit 100"
;; the same works for multiple (send! [:enter id])
```

Probably you should try to employ channels to do that, the scheme is almost the same: `make-timer` would return new channel you can put values on, and read data from there every five seconds (using `alt!` with this channel and `timeout` channel)